# Sending Duplicate Emails with dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud

we're sending emails with highly dynamic content based on data from data extension.

Within a single Job there can be multiple duplicate subscribers, which is OK, because each Email is being delivered to subscriber with unique content.

The problem is: when analysing tracking result within a single Job, we can't tell which email exactly has been opened. The Marketing Cloud's Data View "Opens" contains no field that could be dynamically populated.

Are there any ideas on the workaround? Once again, the goal is: be able to tell which exactly email from the Job has been opened, taking to account that we send the same email to the same recipient multiple times.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: what do you know about SendLog?